# Python: Unicode problems

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I am getting an error at this line

```
logger.info(u"Data: {}".format(data))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Before that line, I tried adding `data = data.decode('utf8')` and I still get the same error.
I tried `data = data.encode('utf8')` and it says `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

How do I fix this? I don't know if I should encode or decode but neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *string* literal:

```
if isinstance(data, unicode):
    data = data.encode('utf8')
logger.info("Data: {}".format(data))
```

The `logging` module needs you to pass in string values as these values are passed on unaltered to formatters and the handlers. Writing log messages to a file means that unicode values are encoded with the default (ASCII) codec otherwise. But you also need to pass in a bytestring value when formatting.

Passing in a `str` value into a `unicode` `.format()` template leads to *decoding* errors, passing in a unicode value into a `str` `.format()` template leads to *encoding* errors, and passing a formatted `unicode` value to `logger.info()` leads to encoding errors too.

Better not mix and encode explicitly beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something such as

data.decode('utf-8').encode("ascii",errors="ignore")

This will "ignore" the unicode characters

edit: data.encode('ascii',error='ignore') may be enough but i'm not in a position to test this currently.